# How to type a component instance when testing with Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

Given I have a component like this

```
interface IState {
  foo
}

interface IProps {
  bar
}

export class MyComp extends Component<IProps, IState> {
  state = {
    foo: 'cool'
  }
}
```

What type should I put for it's instance in enzyme ?

```
    const instance = wrapper.instance()

    expect(instance.state.foo).toEqual('value') 
     // I get type error
     // [ts] Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'
```

Comment: Could you also export the state interface from the component file and use that?

Answer (score 0):

[The return type of the `shallow` is generic](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/enzyme/index.d.ts#L359). So you can pass the types for `Props` and `State`.

```
const componentTree: ShallowWrapper<IProps, IState> = shallow(<MyComponent {...props}/>);   
const instance = componentTree.instance(); 
expect(instance.state.foo).toBe(bar);
```

Enzyme provides an API method to access the component state, so you can directly use that method on the ShallowWrapper to access the component state as follows,

```
const componentTree: ShallowWrapper<IProps, IState> = shallow(<MyComponent {...props}/>); 
expect(componentTree.state().foo).toBe(bar);
```

Both of the above approaches will work.